# OpenCL unexpected high RAM usage

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl, gpgpu, ram

There is a program with a certain amount of kernel (about 30), which operate on common data (*buffers - cl_mem*) and are called in a certain sequence in a loop a large number of times (for example, 100000). The amount of data transferred to the video card is about **x*10 MB**, but the application memory allocation (RAM usage) reaches **several GB** (both in the task manager and in memory usage in Visual Studio).

The algorithm is as follows:

- initialization of opencl (`device, context, queue, programm`)
- loading source data into RAM
- allocation of a large number of buffers for intermediate data `cl_mem Xi = clCreateBuffer (...`
- reloading the source data from RAM to the buffer with `elquequeWriteBuffer (...`
- kernel designation - `cl_kernel k_i = clCreateKernel (...`
- setting arguments for each kernel - `clSetKernelArg (...`
- designation of `global` and `local` sizes for each kernel
- start a loop with a sequence of executable kenel using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (...`

```
for (long int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
  err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (...
  err |= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (...
  ...
  }
```

- read buffer `clEnqueueReadBuffer(`

OpenCl counts everything. The expected result is obtained. But CPU RAM memory usage grows abnormally / disproportionately to the amount of processed data.

I don't understand. I use `cl_mem Xi = clCreateBuffer (...` only one time, I don't create buffer in each iteration, and I creat these buffers only in GPU memory:

`cl_mem buf_input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, X * Y * sizeof(float), NULL, &err);`

**Why so high memory usage at host (CPU RAM)?**

I tried various `clRelease ... (..MemObj, ..Kernel, etc.)`. Also I tried so that the program fully enters the loop (i.e. with overloading and re-copying of the cl-code). All good, but memory ... is growing! And only the application memory. On the GPU RAM usage is about x*10 megabytes.

Comment: Call `clFinish` within the `for` loop. Otherwise the queue is filled faster than it can be emptied, which may cause the high RAM usage.

Comment: If I use ```clFinish(queue)``` calculation speed significantly decresed (from 480 us per iteration to 680 us per iteration). Also GPU load decresed to 50-70% from 100%. But with ```clFinish``` behaviour of RAM usage changed: without this command RAM fast incresed and then not changed until ```for``` finished; with ```clFinish``` it incresed at fixed speed (lineary).

Comment: I try to use ```clReleaseCommandQueue``` after each macro-loop and ```clCreateCommandQueue``` before it: 
`for (int macro=0; macro < 100; macro++) { 
 
  clCreateCommandQueue...
 
  for (long int micro=0; micro < 100000; micro++) { 

    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (... 
 
    }
  clEnqueueReadBuffer(...
  clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
}`

I hope that ```clRelease``` delete queue and clear CPU RAM like ```free(...)```. But RAM usage not decrese after ```clRelease```

Comment: Help! Help! Help!

Answer (score 0):

Bingo! `&event` is main problem!

If I use

`err |= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel17, 2, NULL, tGlobal_k17, tLocal_k17, 0, NULL, &event);`

Host memory incresed, but if I use

`err |= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel17, 2, NULL, tGlobal_k17, tLocal_k17, 0, NULL, NULL);`

host memory is OK!